# How do I perform a Wald Test with multivariate Granger Causality Analysis

Tags: r, time-series

I am doing a Granger Causality Analysis for three economic variables (GDP, CO2 emissions and Total Energy Consumption) of Puerto Rico. I am using a Toda-Yamamoto Procedure implemented in R R. I am basing my code on example given by Christoph Pfieffer in this [blog post](http://www.christophpfeiffer.org/2012/11/07/toda-yamamoto-implementation-in-r/). However, the example that is given in the blog post has two variables, which makes choosing the coefficient for the "Terms" argument fairly easy. I have to do a Wald Test to compare the causality potential of three variables, for example: "GDP Granger-cause Energy Consumption", "Energy Consumption Granger-cause CO2 emissions" and does "GDP Granger cause CO2 emissions"? My question is how do I perform a Wald with three variables and how I choose the coefficient for the "Terms" argument.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a very specific programming question. If you need help with statistical methods, you should post your question to [stats.se] instead where such matters on on-topic. Otherwise create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample code and data to make it clear what the programming question is.

Comment: It can be easily extended as you can see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(urca)
#library(fUnitRoots)
library(urca)
library(vars)
library(aod)
library(zoo)
library(tseries)
data(denmark)

lapply(2:5,function(i)adf.test(denmark[[i]])) # I haven't gone in details over these
lapply(2:5,function(i)adf.test(diff(denmark[[i]]))) # I haven't gone in details over these; you need to check but I assume that they are of I(1)
VARselect(denmark[,2:4],lag=20,type="both") #something like lag 11 is prefered
V.11<-VAR(denmark[,2:4],p=11,type="both") 
serial.test(V.11) # I haven't gone in details over these
1/roots(V.11)[[1]] # I haven't gone in details over these
plot(stability(V.11)) # I haven't gone in details over these
V.12<-VAR(denmark[,2:4],p=12,type="both") # I haven't gone in details over these (add 1 lag as in the linked website)
V.12$varresult # I haven't gone in details over these
summary(V.12) # I haven't gone in details over these

#Wald-test (H0: LRY does not Granger-cause LRM)
wald.test(b=coef(V.12$varresult[[1]]), Sigma=vcov(V.12$varresult[[1]]), Terms=seq(2,33,3))


#Wald-test (H0: LPY does not Granger-cause LRM)
wald.test(b=coef(V.12$varresult[[1]]), Sigma=vcov(V.12$varresult[[1]]), Terms=seq(3,33,3))


#Wald-test (H0: LRM does not Granger-cause LRY)
wald.test(b=coef(V.12$varresult[[2]]), Sigma=vcov(V.12$varresult[[2]]), Terms=seq(1,33,3))

#Wald-test (H0: LPY does not Granger-cause LRY)
wald.test(b=coef(V.12$varresult[[2]]), Sigma=vcov(V.12$varresult[[2]]), Terms=seq(3,33,3))

#Wald-test (H0: LRM does not Granger-cause LPY)
wald.test(b=coef(V.12$varresult[[3]]), Sigma=vcov(V.12$varresult[[3]]), Terms=seq(1,33,3))


#Wald-test (H0: LRY does not Granger-cause LPY)
wald.test(b=coef(V.12$varresult[[3]]), Sigma=vcov(V.12$varresult[[3]]), Terms=seq(2,33,3))
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and coded a specific function that takes a `var` object with two or possible more variables, adds the extra lag and then conducts the Wald test. It returns a data frame with the result.

Note: This function only works for I(1) series, because it adds a single lag. For higher orders of integration, more lags are required.

```
toda.yamamoto <- function(var) {
  # add the magic lag to the existing VAR model
  ty.df <- eval(var$call$y);
  ty.varnames <- colnames(ty.df);
  ty.lags <- var$p + 1;
  ty.augmented_var <- VAR(ty.df, ty.lags, type=var$type);

  ty.results <- data.frame(predictor = character(0), causes = character(0), chisq = numeric(0), p = numeric(0));

  for (current_variable in ty.varnames) {
    # construct the restriction matrix: to test if *current_variable* causes any of the others,
    # we test if the lagged values of current variable (ignoring the magic lag) are jointly insignificant

    ty.restrictions <- as.matrix(Bcoef(ty.augmented_var))*0+1;
    ty.coefres <- head(grep(current_variable, colnames(ty.restrictions), value=T), -1);
    ty.restrictions[which(rownames(ty.restrictions) != current_variable), ty.coefres] <- 0;
    # estimate restricted var
    ty.restricted_var <- restrict(ty.augmented_var, 'manual', resmat=ty.restrictions);

    for (k in 1:length(ty.varnames)) {
      if (ty.varnames[k] != current_variable) {
        my.wald <- waldtest(ty.augmented_var$varresult[[k]], ty.restricted_var$varresult[[k]], test='Chisq');
        ty.results <- rbind(ty.results, data.frame(
                        predictor = current_variable, 
                        causes = ty.varnames[k], 
                        chisq = as.numeric(my.wald$Chisq[2]), 
                        p = my.wald$`Pr(>Chisq)`[2])
        );
      }
    }
  }
  return(ty.results);
}
```